# Use CSS nth-child to select individual table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

The following is the sample table being used. (There can be as many as 'n' rows)

```
<table border="true">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    First Row- First Data
    </td>
    <td>
    First Row- Second Data
    </td>
    <td>
    First Row- Third Data
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink2">First Row- Fourth Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Second Row- First Data
    </td>
    <td>
    Second Row- Second Data
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink3">Second Row- Third Data</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink4">Second Row- Fourth Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Third Row- First Data
    </td>
    <td>
    Third Row- Second Data
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink">Third Row- Third Data</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink4">Third Row- Fourth Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select the first hyperlink in the table row for a column using css selector. This first hyperlink can be present in any row, from 1 to n. In the above case, the hyperlink is in the second row. The following jQuery script shows my current implementation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('table tbody tr td:nth-last-child(2) a:nth-child(1)').css('backgroundColor', 'orange');
});
```

This generates the following output:
[image]

***However, I aim to change background color of only the first hyperlink (in the above case, it might be the second row, but I need a generic selector for nth row) in the third column to orange. Please note that I have to select the element using css selector.***

Comment: Use `tr:first-child` if you only want the first row to be affected.

Comment: Are you trying to find a CSS or jQuery solution to this? The last statement in your question is unclear.

Comment: @Quantastical I'm not sure that's what the OP is asking. It sound like they want the first hyperlink of the column. What if the first hyperlink in the column is in the second row? Using `tr:first-child` would not match it.

Comment: @cyberbit You are right. I want the first hyperlink, and not the first row. I edited the question to clear that confusion.

Comment: @Quantastical I want a css selector to do the job of selecting the dom element.

Comment: @Sandy Using CSS or JavaScript? Would you be applying this functionality into a stylesheet or a JavaScript file?

Comment: @cyberbit I have a custom javascript method that accepts dom element using css selector. I need the css selector for that purpose.

Comment: `first()` is the most clear and concise way of doing this. Using the selectors becomes a jumbled mess.

Comment: @Sandy Is this the expected outcome? http://i.imgur.com/qSEwSZH.png

Comment: @Sandy will there ever be a hyperlink in the first or second columns?

Comment: @Michael_B The table is not fixed. The hyperlink can be from "nth row" in the column. I need the first hyperlink.

Comment: @cyberbit You are right about the expected output. But, please note that the hyperlink may not be in the second row. It can be at any index in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Simply attach a call to `.first()` to your jQuery selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tbody tr td:nth-last-child(2) a:nth-child(1)').first().css('backgroundColor', 'orange');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="true">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        First Row- First Data
      </td>
      <td>
        First Row- Second Data
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="SomeLink">First Row- Third Data</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="SomeLink2">First Row- Fourth Data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Second Row- First Data
      </td>
      <td>
        Second Row- Second Data
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="SomeLink3">Second Row- Third Data</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="SomeLink4">Second Row- Fourth Data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Third Row- First Data
      </td>
      <td>
        Third Row- Second Data
      </td>
      <td>
        Third Row- Third Data
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="SomeLink4">Third Row- Fourth Data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't want to use a jQuery helper method. I just want the selector to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3){background-color:yellow;}
table tbody tr:nth-child() td:nth-child(3){background-color:yellow;}

Answer (score -1):

This is occurring because you are not selecting a specific row (`<tr>`) element. It would be more obvious if the third cell of the third row was also a link. You need to change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('table tbody tr:first-child td:nth-last-child(2) a:nth-child(1)').css('backgroundColor', 'orange');
});
```

The use of `:first-child` allows you to limit changes to the first `<tr>` element of the table.

Comment: Be aware that the question was edited to change requirements after my answer was submitted.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) a:nth-child(1)').css('backgroundColor', 'orange');
}); 
</script>

<table border="true">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    First Row- First Data
    </td>
    <td>
    First Row- Second Data
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink">First Row- Third Data</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink2">First Row- Fourth Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Second Row- First Data
    </td>
    <td>
    Second Row- Second Data
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink3">Second Row- Third Data</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink4">Second Row- Fourth Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Third Row- First Data
    </td>
    <td>
    Third Row- Second Data
    </td>
    <td>
    Third Row- Third Data
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="SomeLink4">Third Row- Fourth Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using `nth-child` only.

Comment: @Sandy Is there any problem in my solution, let me know please.

Comment: The row with the hyperlink is not really the first row. It can be any row. I want the css selector to find that row.